# Removing empty table data cells using jsoup

Tags: android, html, parsing, listview, jsoup

Is there a way using jsoup to remove table cells from the results if they are empty?
The code I have below gathers the information nicely but when I put it into a listview the empty cells show up as empty rows of the list view, 
also 
how can I insert a empty row into the list view after a certain amount of rows?

I know...first I don't want empty rows then I want to specify where I want empty rows.

Code...

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity{

TextView textView1;
ListView shippingList; 

  public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "AppPrefs";
    SharedPreferences settings; 
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;

   @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        //rest of the code

       textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       shippingList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

       settings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
       prefEditor = settings.edit();

       new VTSTask().execute();//starts AsyncTask in private class VTSTask to get shipping info
    }

   private class VTSTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
       ArrayList<String> arr_shipping=new ArrayList<String>();
        /**
         * @param args
         */
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String>  doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Document doc;
            String shippingList;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://vts.mhpa.co.uk/main_movelistb.asp").timeout(600000).get(); 
                //Elements tableRows = doc.select("table.dynlist tr");
              //  Elements tableRows = doc.select("table.dynlist tr:not(:eq(0))td:eq(0),td:eq(1),td:eq(2)");//removes Table Rows
                Elements tableRows = doc.select("table.dynlist td:eq(0),td:eq(1),td:eq(3),td:eq(4),td:eq(5),td:eq(7),td:eq(8)");
                tableRows.size();
                    for(int i = 1; i < 80; i++){//only allows x results from vts list, from 1 not 0. 0 produces needless results
                      shippingList = tableRows.get(i).text() +"\n";

                      arr_shipping.add(shippingList);// add value to ArrayList
                      System.out.println(shippingList);
                    } 
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }      

            return arr_shipping;//<< return ArrayList from here
        }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {        
             //TextView tVShipping=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

             shippingList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                 new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
                                          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                          android.R.id.text1);

             for (String shipping_result : result)
             {
                adapter.add(shipping_result);
             }

             // Assign adapter to ListView
             shippingList.setAdapter(adapter); 

          }
    }


}
```

snippet from website that I'm parsing...

[image: Screen Capture of html]

On the 6th **td** line there is just blank space, sometimes this has information in it sometimes not, so is it possible to filter it out if there is nothing in that cell??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do your job, if you are concerned only about 6<sup>th</sup> `<td>`

```
Element element = doc.select("table.dynlist td:eq(5)").first();

    if(element!= null && text != null && text.replaceAll("&nbsp;| ", "").isEmpty())
    {
        element.remove();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify will this display the data before and after 6th td? and only display the data in td 6 if there is data present? thanks

Comment: The above code just removes the 6th `<td>` only if it has spaces, if not it does nothing.